How to click this button with Selenium?
How do I click all buttons on my page if there are 5 of them or more? I need to do this with Selenium.
Element and source screenshot:

Here is what I've tried:
find_more_element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'products-tile__btn')
while True:
    if not driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'products-tile__btn'):
        with open("link_page.html", "w") as file:
            file.write(driver.page_source)
        break

    else:
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.move_to_element(find_more_element).perform()
        time.sleep(3)


Can you provide the link to the actual page?

of course
https://samara.docke.ru/facade/

"2024"? We generally don't want questions that are expected to go out-of-date, rather than supporting our goal of building up a knowledge base over time. Is there a reason you expect this one to be comparatively short-lived?

When I go to stackoverflow and go to any of the questions about selenium, that library is usually already updated and the code is not working, that's why I specified that it was specifically 2024

what is the problem? Did you get error? Show it in question (not in comments) as text (not image). It would be simpler if you would create minimal working code which we could simply copy and test.

One issue with those buttons is that there are 10 of them on the page but only 2 are visible. So, we'll need to grab all of the buttons, loop through each, check if it's visible, if it is visible then click it. The code below has been tested and works.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

url = 'https://samara.docke.ru/facade/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
buttons = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.products-tile__more")))

for button in buttons:
    if button.is_displayed():
        button.click()


Thanks, chatgpt hepled me with this on the 10th try) But thank you anyway, good decision
